# Node insert cpp

Tags: c++, vector, insert, nodes

How Can I write this 3 Members functions definitions in an one function? if it is possible.Can you also expalain How you did it?.Sorry I'm not good at English and not good at Coding Please don't insult me.

```
 void insert(int idx, PW* obj) 
{
    idx--;
    double bd = summaryCost();
    node x(1);
    x.p = obj;

    if (bd + obj->getCost() <= budget) {
        if (idx <= vec.size()) {
            vec.insert(vec.begin() + idx, x);
            remain -= obj->getCost();
        } else {
            delete obj;
            throw IndexOut();
        }
    } else {
        delete obj;
        throw DeficitError();
    }
}

   void insert(int idx, FW* obj) {
    idx--;
    double bd = summaryCost();
    node x(2);
    x.f = obj;
    if (bd + obj->getCost() <= budget) {
        if (idx <= vec.size()) {
            vec.insert(vec.begin() + idx, x);
            remain -= obj->getCost();
        } else {
            delete obj;
            throw IndexOut();
        }
    } else {
        delete obj;
        throw DeficitError();
    }
}

void insert(int idx, TW* obj) {
    idx--;
    double bd = summaryCost();
    node x(3);
    x.t = obj;
    if (bd + obj->getCost() <= budget) {
        if (idx <= vec.size()) {
            vec.insert(vec.begin() + idx, x);
            remain -= obj->getCost();
        } else {
            delete obj;
            throw IndexOut();
        }
    } else {
        delete obj;
        throw DeficitError();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you mean? I see you have three methods which basically do the same thing with different argument. Do you want just a single method doing this?

Comment: YEs I need a single method doing this

Comment: We can't see the definition of `TW`, `FW` and `PW` so multiple choices are possible here. A template method or directly using inheritance with a common ancestor of all these 3 types.

Comment: You can just make a function having all the three TW, FW & PW as parameters. Based on the object type, execute the code blocks.

Comment: I think that Inheritance would be better. I tried something but I Could not do it .This is the code [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/08uzfcepze3ht1v/AAC1EzNGRvL0Tzc1NjjNptQca?dl=0) in the schedule header

Answer (score 1):

If `PW`, `FW`, and `TW` don't have a common base class, you can use traits classes and templates.

Complete example:

```
// Empty types for illustration purposes.
struct PW {};
struct FW {};
struct TW {};

struct node
{
    node(int i) {}
    PW* p;
    FW* f;
    TW* t;
};

// For readability improvement.
template<typename T>
using member_ptr = T* node::*;

template<typename T>
struct NodeTraits {};

// Class-specific traits
template<>
struct NodeTraits<PW> {
    enum {value = 1};
    static member_ptr<PW> member;
};

template<>
struct NodeTraits<FW> {
    enum {value = 2};
    static member_ptr<FW> member;
};

template<>
struct NodeTraits<TW> {
    enum {value = 3};
    static member_ptr<TW> member;
};

member_ptr<PW> NodeTraits<PW>::member = &node::p;
member_ptr<FW> NodeTraits<FW>::member = &node::f;
member_ptr<TW> NodeTraits<TW>::member = &node::t;

// Finally, the function...
template<typename T>
void insert(int idx, T* obj) 
{
    node x(NodeTraits<T>::value);
    member_ptr<T> ptr = NodeTraits<T>::member;
    x.*ptr = obj;
    // ...
}

// Using it...
int main()
{
    PW p;
    FW f;
    TW t;
    insert(0, &p);
    insert(0, &f);
    insert(0, &t);
}
```

Explanation left as an exercise for the interested reader.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your dropbox code, it seems that you need to spend a little more time looking into virtual functions, and c++ pure virtual functions; which allow you to do something like

```
struct ChargeableItem {
  virtual int getCost() = 0;
};

struct WorkItem : ChargeableItem {
  virtual int getCost() {return 5;}
}

int total = 0;
void insert(ChargeableItem* i) {
  total += i->getCost();
}

int main() {
  WorkItem x;
  insert(&x);
}
```

Note there's a lot of bad practices in the above code, but I think it's ultimately what you're trying to do.